# Is there any way to tackle the problem of shifting right in erosion OpenCv?

Tags: python, opencv

I used dilation and erosion OpenCV multiple time on one object, but it seems that at the end the eroded object is not centered, it is in the right bottom corner of the object before dilation and erosion. How does it works? I mean how can I fix the problem so the eroded object would be centered?

Comment: You'll need to provide some code and images for an MCVE

Comment: Please show code and result. Are you perhaphs using a kernel with even size?

Comment: Use odd kernel size like 3x1, 1x3, 3x3, 5x1, 1x5, 5x5, 7x7... even size like 4x4 may "shift" the image content.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks, it is solved by putting odd kernels.